# Defining new methods on Object.prototype results in various errors

Tags: node.js

I was trying to define a method on **`Object.prototype`**

```
Object.prototype.myNewMethod = function() {
    return this;
};
```

but one module or another keeps throwing error

> ```
> C:\~\node_modules\twilio\lib\resources\generate.js:89
>                 object[key] = object[method[key].toLowerCase()];
>                                                  ^
> TypeError: Object function () {
>     return this;
> } has no method 'toLowerCase'
>     at Function.generate.restFunctions (C:\~\node_modules\twilio\lib\resources\generate.js:89:50)
>     at module.exports (C:\~\node_modules\twilio\lib\resources\ListInstanceResource.js:29:14)
>     at mixinResources (C:\~\node_modules\twilio\lib\resources\Accounts.js:18:31)
>     at module.exports (C:\~\node_modules\twilio\lib\resources\Accounts.js:108:5)
>     at new RestClient (C:\~\node_modules\twilio\lib\RestClient.js:54:58)
>     at initializer (C:\~\node_modules\twilio\lib\index.js:14:12)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\~\server\socket.js:17:31)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>     at require (module.js:380:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\~\server\app.js:40:17)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>     at startup (node.js:119:16)
>     at node.js:906:3
> ```

I remove the above module, another one throws an error:

> ```
> C:\~\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:296
>           throw err;
>                 ^
> TypeError: Object function () {
>     return this;
> } has no method 'onOpen'
>     at open (C:\~\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:450:27)
>     at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (C:\~\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:461:5)
>     at C:\~\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:421:10
>     at C:\~\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:59:5
>     at C:\~\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:293:11
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
> ```

Comment: Adding methods on Object.prototype is widely [considered a terrible practice](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/). Why are you doing this ?

Comment: @dystroy Is it, I didn't know better. What should I do if I want to make a my own `toString` like function for all objects?

Comment: Well, you should just use a function taking objects as parameters, not try to add methods on any objects.

Comment: That's because your method is a method and not a string. Also what dystroy said.